# jar не видит ресурсы

Tags: java, maven, resources

Пытаюсь запустить пакет из созданного jar, но проблема в том, что он не видит ресурсы. В IDEA работает нормально. Пользуюсь Maven.

*Выкидывает две ошибки:*

> file:/C:/Users/andrew/IdeaProjects/eitsoft/target/Jfemvisualization-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/scenes/monitoring_window.fxml
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\andrew\IdeaProjects\eitsoft\target\Jfemvisualization-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\values\colors.xml

*В IDE все работает прекрасно:*

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("scenes/monitoring_window.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Monitoring");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));
    primaryStage.show();
```

*pom.xml:*

```
 <groupId>ru.eit-Jfemvisualization.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Jfemvisualization</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ru.app.monitoring.view.MonitoringWindow</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случаях, когда ресурсы запакованы внутри jar-файла доступ к ним необходимо осуществлять через InputStream. В IDE всё работает потому что при таком сценарии происходит простая компиляция без упаковки в jar'ник. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/6366534

Answer (score 0):

Положите Ваши ресурсы в resources/scenes и обращайтесь к ним вот так:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/scenes/monitoring_window.fxml"));
```

Comment: Они там и лежат

Comment: Это хорошо, что он там и лежит, но, я как минимум, вижу в Вашем коде идет неверное обращение к ресурсам (без начального /).

Comment: если ставлю в начало / мне выдает `Location is required` в IDE

Comment: Покажите ваше расположение resources в проекте. А так же посмотрите лежат ли ваши ресурсы в финальном jar.